# Getting redirect loop when pass custom Request type into action Laravel 5

Tags: php, forms, laravel, request

I have contoroller action, where I want to render form and handle it submitted, so here what I am do:

```
public function add(PostFormRequest $request)
{
    if (Input::get('title')) {
        $post = new Post(Input::all());
        if ($post->save()) {
            return redirect('posts');
        }
    }

    return view('add_post');
}
```

But I getting redirect loop, when I use just `public function add()` all fine, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think it's redirecting in this code, you can test by setting a `dd('here');` before your `return redirect('posts');`. What's in the PostFormRequest?

Comment: @Robert, it looks like it does not go inside the action, `var_dump(1);die;`, right after actiion begin bracket does not work and getting redirect loop...

Comment: Then it's getting redirected in the PostFormRequest. Can you post that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your form request probably contains some validation rules. Those will obviously fail on the GET request and it will redirect, fail, redirect and so on. Form requests are always injected and validated. Not just on POST requests. The best and in general more clean solution is to just split it up in two different methods.

Comment: yes I get it. but I dont like this approach,because for my opinion it does not makes our controllers more beaty,instead of single fully action we getting two, and its just only for creation, two for updating, and we still remember for routes,  it will be four routes,so instead of avoid FSUC we getting large sheet.maybe someone like this, maybe someday I will love that too.but for now I think Laravel need to work on validating using the model.maybe someone says no it flexible for now. oh. every day I am more and more sure that programming is no clear boundaries, and we need balance beetwen that

Comment: You don't have to use form requests. You can use Laravels validator manually or inside your model. There are multiple packages for model validation as well.